# Energy-delay-product vs. Joule to watt conversion formula

Tags: energy, efficiency

I am currently on my master's doing an assignment, and I am in this point in time extremely confused and I was wondering about this, quite possibly, stupid question. I am just too afraid to ask at this point in time.

If a system requires 5 watt, this equals the system consuming 5 joules per second. The formula for converting watts to joules is given as E(j) = T(s) * P(w).

Another commonly used metric is the energy delay product, which is given as E(j) = D(s) * P(w), where delay denotes the time it takes to execute a given workload. Is the energy-delay product not the same as converting watts to joules? Am I a complete idiot? If they are equal, why would it have a name of its own?

I understand that this is stupid, but I just need to ask the question.

Comment: Is this specifically an EE question?

Comment: Delay is an elapsed time, so sounds synonymous to me. Who knows why people in particular disciplines will use an unusual term for the same quantity. I've never heard the term delay product before, in what field is it 'commonly used'?

Comment: Please use the correct capitalisation: E(J) = T(s) * P(W). You *convert* between units of measurements for the same physical quantity, not between any two unlike physical quantities. Energy, time, and power are in the stated relation, and given any two, you can compute the third. Never heard of [*energy-delay product*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power%E2%80%93delay_product#cite_note-Gaudet_2014-1), *power*-delay product has been around. And yes, it's an energy. There are different name for essentially the same unit to ease interpretation.